# Why do multiple font sizes display inside Plain TextBox?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-4.5

This is not a question about how to change the font size. Rather, why is the size of my font changing by itself as I type (or paste) when it's inside a plain `TextBox` control which, as you should know, only supports one color, one font, and one font size at any given time.

My code:

```
using(FontDialog d = new FontDialog())
{
   // The usual properties...
   if(d.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
   {
      textbox1.Font = d.Font;
   }
}
```

The font is set at 8pt. If I paste plain text into it, the top line will be 9 to 10pt while the bottom line is noticeably smaller (about 8 pt).

It doesn't matter which font, font style, or font size I choose; this keeps happening!

[image]

## Update

Thanks for all your help thus far.To answer your recent questions below:

My app is targetting .NET 4.5.

There's no mix up in the code, since I was able to reproduce this problem in a new Windows Forms project with nothing but a Form, a TextBox and a Button that calls the FontDialog.

To answer the question about my Video drivers, I did require support for an app I purchased a few weeks ago and they told me to run DXDiag, they got back to me saying my Video Card driver is out of date, however I didn't think it was because I always check every few months. I then went to the manufacturer's website and it said that I already have the latest drivers installed for my system.

Windows Update also says there are no new available updates. I'll check for a new version of drivers again, though.

---

I also did a test in a new blank project where I display the font being used by the TextBox *before* calling FontDialog.ShowDialog(), and after it has been shown and after the new font has been set and everything matches - yet there is still the issues after changing font/font size inside the textbox.

Comment: What happens when the control is programmatically populated -- IE, not by pasting?

Comment: Are you SURE that's a TextBox, and not a RichTextBox?

Comment: Just tested; the same thing happens. Bigger size on first line, smaller size on second line. I'm scared.

Comment: @MichaelPaulukonis yep! And this will prove it: Cannot paste anything into it other than plain text; There is no Rtf property in intellisense for this control and not to mention; I have TextBox tb = new (); up the top of the page :)

Comment: I wonder if it has to do with the using block disposing the FontDialog. Try not disposing and see what happens.

Comment: Can you reproduce this on a new project?

Comment: I just repro'd this in a new project and it has the same effect. @DavidH, I just tried your suggestion and so far with a few different fonts and sizes it appers to be normal again (without the using block). I'm not sure why this would be affecting it though, since the textbox font is being set within the using block (unless the using block disposes of it before the font is actually changed, but then that doesn't make sense because the font does change :-/ I'm curious about why you thought it was the using block?

Comment: The best practice for Dispose methods is that all base/parent classes are ALSO disposed... Not super familiar with fonts or windows forms apps to be honest, but one thing you can do is debug and look at the Font object before and after the using block and see what changes, if anything.

Comment: +1. Can anyone else reproduce it (except OP)?

Comment: Can you upload your project to DropBox or other file share service?  My guess is either you made a mixup in your code, or you have some windows styling tool installed.

Comment: Start stripping everything out of the program until you have the simplest program that still duplicates the problem. If while doing this the problem goes away, you just found the source of the problem. If not, post the complete sample here.

Comment: Please also mention which .NET framework version you are targeting.

Comment: Is your computer's video driver up-to-date?

Comment: I have been able to reproduce this in a new, blank project, I'm targetting NET 4.5, DXDiag reported that mly drivers are _not_ up to date, however upon checking with the manufacturer's website (and their update assistant) I have been told that my drivers _are_ up to date. I tried doing a rollback and reinstalling/the drivers I already had but that hasn't made a difference.

Comment: I just had a thought, if it were my video drivers that were out of date, wouldn't this be happening all over the place? For example, in Notepad, or MS Word or Excel? And not just my most recent WinForms apps? My older apps have not been affected.

Comment: Please show the code where textbox1 is created.

Comment: Hey. I'm getting the inverse behavior (first line small, other lines larger) in MS NOTEPAD today, with text pasted from Facebook. That's not a RichText box, is it? And it's the first line, not the text -- as I change the shape of the window, the text flow maintains the sizes of the lines, regardless of the amount of text (ie, 1 word or 50).

Comment: This is weird. I noticed there were updates to windows that were installed a few days ago and then again today. Maybe it's a system thingy that's causing this? I mean, All I'm doing is `TextBox tb = new TextBox();` and somehow, the font is screwed, now I don't see how that could screw up a font's display. There must be something else going on. But then again, if it were a system problem, it would be affecting more than just my 2 latest app's textboxes, right?

Comment: Notepad's is a TextBox I believe. RichTextBox controls can handle much larger amounts of text than a regulat TextBox can handle -and Notepad struggled to load a 2 - 3 MB file most of the time, so I doubt that it's a RTB.

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't have such a problem.

Comment: I'm glad you are not having this problem, @KingKing. I just wish it wasn't me.

Comment: Have tried re-painting (textbox1.Invalidate(); textBox1.Update()) the text box after setting a font? Or even handle re-creating?

  textBox1.GetType().GetMethod("RecreateHandle", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).Invoke(textBox1, new Object[0]);

Comment: So you're creating a dynamic TextBox.  Are you assigning the Font before or after it is placed in a container/form?  Also, are you doing this before or after the Form has been shown?  Just trying to establish **when** this code is occurring.

Comment: Always doing this stuff after Form1_Shown() is raised. And I have tried setting the font both before and after the TextBox is placed inside a TabPage/Form/Container/Panel.

Comment: I encountered a pseudo-related issue when playing with a TextBox derived control.  In that case settings weren't "taking" when the control started out in a disabled state (solved by enabling the control, performing some code, then disabling it again).  Can you give more details about how this TextBox is being used?  What is the "big picture" here?...

Comment: @Idle_Mind: Think of Windows Notepad. Now think of a Tab-based Notepad. That's all there is to it, really; When a new tab is created, a new textbox (with DockStyle.Fill) is added to the TabPage. There really isn't any more to it than that. It's just a plain old textbox that gets created at runtime when you click a button.

Comment: It is interesting to note that all the letter o's in your sample are the same height (6px) it is just the width that is different. I suspect that there is some kind of scale issue going on here. Are you using a high DPI screen? Does the text change if you move the form around the screen?

Comment: Have you tried putting the same text on both lines?

Comment: Yep. High DPI and I have tried placing same text on both lines; Moving the form around and re-painting doesn't have any effect.

Comment: Are you running these projects in the debugger? Have you tried publishing one of the projects and running it? How about running the published executable on another machine? I would first try to establish whether it is just your machine. If the effect is reproduced on other machines with different hardware configurations then you can start to look at the way your code is being generated.

Comment: I have not had the chance to test it on another machine. Yes, I'm running in the debugger, but I've also published - many times. Problem still exists in published version.

Comment: I've got a question about your input data: Is one string a different subset of unicode to another? i.e. is one line ASCII and another unicode characters > 128 that look similar?

Comment: It looks like an OS bug. Reinstall windows (or run it on another pc :) ) to see if the OS is broken or the app is broken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that the High-DPI screen that you are using is not using an exact multiple of 96 DPI. When in this situation Windows renders your application to a virtual screen that is 96 DPI and then rescales the result to the new DPI. Having a DPI that is not an exact multiple of 96 can cause rounding errors when the application's display is rescaled and as a result fonts can end up looking uneven.

Try setting your DPI to one of the sizes in [Appendix C](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd464660%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#Appendix_C_Optimal_DPI_Configuration_Examples) of Microsoft's [Writing High-DPI Win32 Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd464660%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) guide.

Comment: I think this is actually the issue. I just plugged my friend's monitor in that he left over here. The fonts look normal when his screen's plugged in. Thanks :-)

Comment: sorry it took so long to accept this answer. I don't know how I forgot about it! Thanks again :)